# How can I inject a Class of an object, not an object itself

Tags: spring, class, inject, factory-method

I'm trying to inject a list of Class. I want a list of classes, not objects.

My class looks like this:

```
public class CodeServiceImpl{

    private List<Class<?>> codeList;

// getter and setter
```

My spring configuration file (I'm not using annotations but xml) is

```
<bean id="myCodeServiceImpl" class = "net.croz.service.CodeServiceImpl">
        <property name="codeList">
            <list>
                <ref bean="myAddress"/>
                <ref bean="myCity"/>
                <ref bean="myCountry"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="myAddress" class="java.lang.Class" factory-method="forName">
            <constructor-arg value="net.croz.model.Address"/> 
        </bean>

        <bean id="myCity" class="java.lang.Class" factory-method="forName">
            <constructor-arg value="net.croz.model.City"/> 
        </bean>

        <bean id="myCountry" class="java.lang.Class" factory-method="forName">
            <constructor-arg value="net.croz.model.Country"/>
        </bean>
```

But the list codeList isn't being populated. It ends up being a null object. Thank you for your help.

Comment: 1) How do you obtain the `CodeServiceImpl` instance? 2) Are you accessing the `codeList` in its constructor?

Comment: Oh, boy I feel so stupid. You hit the little demon I couldn't see for two hours. I was just using a constructor. Of course spring doesn't inject it if you don't actually call the bean in question. Again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it works as is:

```
<bean class="com.my.proj.Foo">
        <constructor-arg value="java.lang.String, org.springframework.util.StringUtils, byte[]"/>
</bean>
```

where `Foo` is:

```
public class Foo {

    private final List<Class<?>> codeList;

    public Foo(Class<?>... codeList) {
        this.codeList = Arrays.asList(codeList);
    }

}
```

The `ConversionService` does the stuff for converting comma-separated string to the `Class<?>[]` and tries to resolve each class on its own using `BeanClassLoader`

Comment: Yes, I made a dumb mistake of just making an instance of a class and expecting it to act like a bean I declared without actually calling the bean in question.